# Will an 0603 capacitor fit on an 0805 pad?

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount, layout

I am in a pinch and just submit my final board design to a pcb house. Unfortunately, I messed up the design and had an 0805 pad in a spot where a an 0603 should have been. I will be getting the boards in this Friday with a 2-day turn.

Can I get an 0603 to fit on the 0805 pad in a pinch? I know it's not ideal, I just need to know if it will work so I don't have to pay 25$ to overnight 50 cents worth of capacitors from mouser or digi-key.

I did a mock up on a scale printout and it looks VERY close like it should be fine.

Comment: Are you doing hand assembly? Probably it will work. Worst case you'll need to do a little solder "sculpting" to bridge the gap.

Comment: How are you assembling the board?  By hand you can do this carefully, but I wouldn't want to rely on reflow without glue.

Comment: Well, I am going to re-flow as much as I can, but I have hot air to do anything that needs a hand touch... David and Photon, thank you. I just wanted to double check. It visually looks like it should work out on my printout. Thank you guys!

Comment: It's worked fine when I've done it with hand soldering.

Comment: Someday, you'll even solder 0402 capacitors across the leads of SOIC components. You'll get used to the idea of hacking things together with blobs of solder, scratching through soldermask, cutting traces with an X-acto knife, and tombstoning components to make things fit. It's called "prototyping."

Comment: HA!!  I accidentally ordered an 0402 capacitor for this project and it was about the size of a grain of sand. Completely unbelievable!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using 'standard' footprints then yes, an 0603 will fit fine on an 0805 pad. The reverse works too, in a pinch.